# Можно ли сделать div такого вида?

Tags: css, html

надо сделать див такого плана, и чтобы дочерние элементы были в закрашенной области, можно так сделать?
[image]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться трюком с `box-shadow`

```
  box-shadow: 0 /*Горизонтальный отступ*/
              0 /*Вертикальный отступ*/
              0 /*Размытие*/
              30px /* "Распостранение" */ 
              teal /* Цвет */
              inset /* Внутри элемента */;
```

```css
.wrapper
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px teal inset;
}
.inside
{
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="inside">Inside the container</div>
</div>
```